# Can I Allocate memory dynamically inside of class's constructor?

Tags: java, android, class, constructor

So, here's what I have written on my code. This is the declaration part of the code (written in JAVA).

```
private class DataStructure{
        private VoltageMsg[] voltageMsg;
        public DataStructure()
        {
            this.voltageMsg = new VoltageMsg[VOLTAGE_CH];
        }
        private class VoltageMsg{
            private int Decimal;
            private int Integer;
            private int ch;
            public void setter(int Decimal, int Integer, int ch){
                this.Decimal = Decimal;
                this.Integer = Integer;
                this.ch = ch;
            }
        }
}
```

VOLTAGE_CH is constant by the way declared in certain integer value.
I tried to use the class like this,

```
private DataStructure datas;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        datas = new DataStructure();
}
```

and here's the part when fatal exception happened.

```
datas.voltageMsg[0].setter(1,2,3);
```

here's the specific message that I copied from logcat.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.wise.ksj.kitms_monitoring_device.DeviceStatus$DataStructure$VoltageMsg.setter(int, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

What did I do wrong?  Can I not allocate memory dynamically inside of the constructor like I did? Is that why it keeps showing me this fatal exception? As you can probably guess by now, I'm pretty new to these whole software engineering/programming stuff. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `new VoltageMsg[VOLTAGE_CH]` only creates the array. You still have to instantiate each element individually; e.g., `voltageMsg[0] = new VoltageMsg();`.

Comment: @Mike M. Thank you! It worked!